# Command substitution in the same shell, db2 reports no connection

Tags: bash, db2

I have the following snippet in a bash script:

```
db2 connect to $DB
var=$(db2 -x "$query" | tr -d " ")
```

`$query` holds a `select count` query, `-x` just prints out the result of the command with no headers so `var` would be assigned to a number.

What happens is that `$(...)` is executed in a subshell and doesn't inherit the connection to DB2 resulting in the "`SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003`" message.

I don't know how does the `db2 connect` command affects the environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One hint:  Set the DB2DBDFT environment variable to the name of the database you want to use:   it will enable the DB2 CLP to make an implicit connection (if you are running on the database server).

```
$ export DB2DBDFT=sample
$ db2 "select count(*) from empphoto"  # <-- no "db2 connect to sample" needed.
```

This also helps to make subshells work.

```
#!/bin/ksh

export DB2DBDFT=sample
count=$(db2 -x "select count(*) from empphoto" | awk '{print $1}')
print "Count is ${count}"
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you can do all your variable processing in a subshell you can do something like this:

```
db2 connect to $DB
db2 -x "$query" | tr -d " " | {
    read var
    do-stuff with var
}
```

However, you'll have to use temporary files or named pipes to get variable values back to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics here: the first command 'db2 connect to $DB' probably finishes, and made a connection. As soon as it finished however it also closed it.

It sounds like you want a construct rather like this:

```
var=$(db2 -x "connect to $DB;$query" | tr -d " ")
```

IOW: run db2 command and let him first execute 'connect to $DB' (the shell will have replaced $DB for you) and then '$query' (again the shell did the replacement.)

I'm not sure which separator db2 wants, so ';' was a guess.

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarified it, but db2 commands require the db2 connect to initialize the session and then you can send db2 whatever, at the end there is a db2 connect reset to finish the session.

Comment: I tried the $(db2 connect ... ) etc but this runs inside a loop etc. and slow things a lot.